# about SQL Server xml dml

Tags: sql-server, xml, dml

I want insert  into two element in if statements，for example：

```
x.modify('insert if (/a)>1') then element **a{1} b{1}**
```

…………………………

a{1} b{1} is not allowed together.
please tell me how to deal with it. thx

Comment: Please state your XML **before** the modification and your expected output **after** the modification. And explain the business rules (about the `if (/a)>1`) in normal words...

Comment: @Shnugo  i want to have two elements after element.....x.modify('insert if (/a)>1') then element (a{1} b{1}  else() as last into /)

Comment: Sorry, No idea what you want. Please use the edit Option to füll this into your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a{1} b{1} is not allowed together. please tell me how to deal with it

Have a look at [Sequence Expressions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/sequence-expressions-xquery).

```
declare @X xml = '<a>2</a>';
set @X.modify('insert (element a{1}, element b{1}) as last into (/a[text() > 1]/..)[1]');
select @X;
```

Result:

```
<a>2</a>
<a>1</a>
<b>1</b>
```